# Showing $ u =0 $ for a particular laplace equation.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, dirac-delta

Given open $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ with smooth enough boundary, if for $x_0 \in \Omega$ there exists $ u \in C^2(\Omega\setminus\{x_0\}) $( we may as well take $u$ as smooth as we want) that satisfies 
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   \Delta u = 0 & \text{ in } \Omega\setminus\{x_0\} \\
   u = 0 & \text{ in } \partial\Omega
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then for some $ y \in \Omega\setminus\{x_0\}$ if $u(y) = 0 $ then is it true that $ u = 0 $ everywhere in $\Omega$ ?
I can see that $ \Delta u = \sum_\alpha C_\alpha D^\alpha \delta_{x_0} $ in sense of distribution, hence perhaps $ u(x) = \sum_\alpha C_\alpha D^\alpha G(x,x_0) $ where $G$ is the green's function. Probably a good use of maximum principle would do it but I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume that for any sequence $x_n\in \Omega\setminus \{x_0\}$ with $x_n\to x_0$, we have that  $$\liminf u(x_n)>0$$

hence, by the maximum principle $u(x)>0$ in $\Omega\setminus \{x_0\}$. On the other hand, if for any sequence $x_n\in \Omega\setminus \{x_0\}$ with $x_n\to x_0$, we have that $$\limsup u(x_n)<0$$

then, by the maximum principle $u(x)<0$ for $x\in \Omega\setminus \{x_0\}$. To conclude, if $u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ and $u(x_0)=0$ then $u$ must be zero everywhere.

For some references, take a look [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.axler.net%2FHFT.pdf&ei=RYcbU8aZKsPUkQf2gIHQCA&usg=AFQjCNEh4a0-zGzNs0JcRj1MF5NxB4u4cg&bvm=bv.62578216,d.eW0) in pages 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

For a bounded domain $\Omega$ with $\,\partial\Omega\in C^1$, it is obviously true if $\,u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ and $x_0\,$ is a removable singular point. Of course, it cannot be true whenever a singularity  $x_0\,$ be non-removable, *e.g.*, take $\,\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\colon\,\,|x|<1\}\,$ with $\,x_0=0$, and consider an example of $\,u(x)= x_1 x_2\bigl(1-|x|^{-4}\bigr)$.  It is clear that $\,u\in C^2(\Omega\backslash \{x_0\})\,$ and $\,\Delta u=0\,$ in $\,\Omega\backslash \{x_0\}$,  while $\,u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$.  But $\,u=0\,$ on the lines $\,x_1=0\,$ and $\,x_2=0\,$ inside $\,\Omega\backslash \{x_0\}\,$, while $u\not\equiv 0$.